# Could not find conceptual model for type 'ModelType'

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, msbuild

I'm currently trying to deploy a Silverlight app with a RIA services link to a Web Application Project. This app also uses Devart dotConnect for Oracle (an EF system for oracle).

When running MSBuild on the csproj file I am getting the error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight\v3.0\Microsoft.Ria.Client.targets(261,5): error : Could not find the conceptual model type for 'ModelType'
```

Where ModelType is the name of one of the classes in the diagram.

Has anyone else ever come across this error? I am struggling to locate the root cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem of Silverlight 3.
One of our users have already found a [workaround](http://www.devart.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=18544) for this:
* Change the file extension from .edml to .edmx
* Remove the Silverlight project from solution
* Compile solution using 64-bit MSBuild
Actually, upgrade to Silverlight 4 also solves the problem.

Comment: The irony of this answer is that the user you reference sits across from me in the office, and the fix mentioned does not seem to work as expected (we're having deployment issues still, hence the post). Upgrading to silverlight 4 is not an option, unfortunately.

Comment: The world is a small place... Unfortunately, we are unable to suggest anything better than renaming and changing the Build Action.

Comment: Ok: after some investigation I discovered that you can indeed do it like this, the reason it was not working when I tried it was due to the way I was processing the MSBuild script. As I was running my custom EdmlToEdmx task as the last task before build, and the EntityDeploy task is run as the very first task, you have to override the EntityDeploy task and provide it with a dependency if you want to automate the conversion. Thanks for the help.